# Results missing data between two dates with BETWEEEN or >= and <=

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Starting with...

```
SET @DATEFROM = '2014-04-01'
SET @DATETO = '2014-10-01'
```

..., I am trying to query with the following filters:

```
C.DateCreate BETWEEN @DATEFROM AND @DATETO)
```

or

```
C.DateCreate >= @DATEFROM AND C.DateCreate <= @DATETO
```

Both return the same result set, which does not include the current month's (October's) data.

I want the data for October.  Apparently that is what I am setting.  Is there a workaround to achieve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want October and you want to use those limits, I would recommend:

```
C.DateCreate >= @DATEFROM AND C.DateCreate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @DATETO)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it helps me a lot :) :) :) Wow I got it resolved. But any side affect does it have?

Comment: I have another query where the date part in where condition is: convert(date, C.DateCreate) >= CONVERT(date, @DATE).....Now I want the same functionality. i.e I wanna have DateFrom and DateTo in the similar way. Please give me hints. Its little complex here, just trying though at my end too

Comment: @Divine: If you have another question, ask it as another question. If the answers to this question don't address the problem, you are likely dealing with a different issue that warrants a distinct question.

Comment: Gordan and JOe3gan, I have completed this myself, yay, thank you so much guys :) All problems in this quetion solved :) :) I am happy....(convert(date, C.DateCreate) >= CONVERT(date, @DATEFROM) AND convert(date, C.DateCreate) < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @DATETO)))

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering for everything between April 1st and October 1st - and including nothing in October.  Pretty simple really.  Maybe you have been staring at this too long (seriously, not sarcastically).

Try this if you just want everything in October 2014:

```
SET @DATEFROM = '2014-10-01' -- or '2014-04-01' if you truly want to include data back to April
SET @DATETO = '2014-11-01'

-- .
-- .
-- .
C.DateCreate >= @DATEFROM AND C.DateCreate < @DATETO
```

Note that I replaced `<=` with `<` in the `@DATETO` comparison and set `@DATETO` to November 1 rather than October 31 - since the former is midnight on November 1 (i.e. anything less than this falling into October down to the last moment like you want).